# What is the set of all of the graphs of a function called?

Tags: functions

Imagine, for instance, we have a set that has all of the possible domains and ranges of every possible combination of inputs of a function.

Here's an example:

The equation for Polytropes in astrophysics:

[image: Polytrope Equation]

Here's the, what I like to call, the animated "Graph space", or set of the domains and ranges:

[Polytrope “Graph Space”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytrope#/media/File:Polytropes.gif)

What is the name of the data described by this animation?

Comment: Not everything has a name

Comment: Given some function $f: A \to B$, the graph $G$ of $f$ is $G = \{(x,y) : x \in A, y = f(x)\}$. You are asking for "the set of all possible domains and ranges of every possible comination of inputs of a function," which is not entirely clear. I suspect you are asking for the powerset of $G$?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I believe this is correct, as far as my knowledge of this topic goes.

Comment: The animation you linked would probably best be described as a "parameterized function", but that's not at all what you've asked for in your first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some function $f:A \to B$, the graph $G$ of $f$ is $G=\{(x,y):x\in A,y=f(x)\}$. I suspect you are asking for the **powerset** of $G$. This would be the set of all possible subsets of $G$. You could think of it as the set of all possible subsets of inputs into $f$ such that each input $x$ is accompanied by its corresponding output $f(x)$.

Comment: So it is also a parameterized function encompassing all variables?

Comment: I would not equate a powerset with a function. you seem to be asking two separate questions in the title of the post and within the post itself. Are you trying to figure out what to call the animation?

Comment: No, I am trying to find a name for all of the domains and ranges with every possible value for every possible variable of a function.